# encoding unicode using UTF-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, encode

In Python, if I type

```
euro = u'\u20AC'
euroUTF8 = euro.encode('utf-8')
print(euroUTF8, type(euroUTF8), len(euroUTF8))
```

the output is

```
('\xe2\x82\xac', <type 'str'>, 3)
```

I have two questions:
   1. it looks like euroUTF8 is encoded over 3 bytes, but how do I get its binary representation to see how many bits it contain?
   2. what does `'x'` in `'\xe2\x82\xac'` mean? I don't think `'x'` is a hex number. And why there are three `'\'`?

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, not a function. You are printing a *tuple* here. Print the individual elements by removing the `(..)`:

```
>>> euro = u'\u20AC'
>>> euroUTF8 = euro.encode('utf-8')
>>> print euroUTF8, type(euroUTF8), len(euroUTF8)
€ <type 'str'> 3
```

Now you get the 3 individual objects written as strings to stdout; my terminal just happens to be configured to interpret anything written to it as UTF-8, so the bytes correctly result in the `€` Euro symbol being displayed.

The `\x<hh>` sequences are *Python string literal escape sequences* (see the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)); they are the default output for the `repr()` applied to a string with non-ASCII, non-printable bytes in them. You'll see the same thing when echoing the value in an interactive interpreter:

```
>>> euroUTF8
'\xe2\x82\xac'
>>> euroUTF8[0]
'\xe2'
>>> euroUTF8[1]
'\x82'
>>> euroUTF8[2]
'\xac'
```

They provide you with ASCII-safe debugging output. The contents of all Python standard library containers use this format; including lists, tuples and dictionaries.

If you want to format to see the bits that make up these values, convert each byte to an integer by using the `ord()` function, then format the integer as binary:

```
>>> ' '.join([format(ord(b), '08b') for b in euroUTF8])
'11100010 10000010 10101100'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Each letter in each encoding are represented using different number of bits. UTF-8 is a 8 bit encoding, so there is no need to get a binary representation to know each bit count of each character. (If you still want to present bits, refer to Martijn's answer.)
2. `\x` means that the following value is a byte. So x is not something like a hex number that you should convert or read. It identifies the following value, which is you are interested in. `\`'s are used to escape that `x`'s because they are not a part of the value.